# SDL_Surface Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sdl, sdl-2, surface

so here's my problem(s). I have a class DrawMgr in which function DrawCube I call, my other class' function draw in which I use SDL_Surface. My main problem is that when I start moving the mouse over the window I created after some time it gives a segmentation fault, which when I backtrace says it has something to do with freeing the surface. The other thing is when I call the function DrawCube in the DrawManager.cpp it doesn't draw the cube.

**EDIT:** The problem was that I handled the "Escape" key with `e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE`, which captured all movement within the window which made it crash. The correct way was `e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && e.key.keysym.sym...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SDL_GetWindowSurface](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface) documentation says **This surface will be freed when the window is destroyed. Do not free this surface.**